# How to intercept FORM results

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter

I need to remotely submit/process a form on an external website and get the results back on my site. The user can NOT be aware of this interaction.

I am able to get the data using HTML PHP/ Simple_Html_Dom

```
<?php
require "DOM/simple_html_dom.php";

$html = file_get_html('website.com/pricing');
foreach ($html->find('div[id=Price]') as $result)
{
    echo $result->innertext;
}

?>
```

It is returning, PRICE as N/A.  I need to be able to pass the values of the fields. I was hoping to pass them as hidden values such as `<input type="hidden" name="QTY" value="100" />`

What is the proper syntax and/or how do I accomplish this task?

I tried:

```
$html->load('<html><body
<form action="website.com/..." method="post" name="Pricing" > 
#all hidden fields & values
</form></body></html>')
```

Any ideas? Thanks for the help. Ideally I am trying to recreate the form on my page and fetch the results of the query in real-time using AJAX.

--MORE DATA--
This page is using sessions: (How does this affect POST?)

```
{
"headers": {
"Date": "Mon, 24 Sep 2012 19:23:58 GMT",
"Server": "Apache",
"Set-Cookie": "JSESSIONID=01987F6C188624B08885FE26644300DA.worker2; Path=/g",
"Cache-Control": "no-cache",
"Pragma": "no-cache",
"P3P": "CP=\"IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT\"",
"Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
"Connection": "close",
"Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
"Content-Type": "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
},
```

Comment: is the other page under your control?

Comment: no... some research is leading me to believe that a PHP Proxy POST is the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access or amend data coming via AJAX that are from another domain. There is a [same domain policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) in force for such requests, so various types of hacks are prevented (like sniffing someone's browser for their bank account details).

If you cannot control pages in question, you are (as your research suggested) left with an option of a [PHP Proxy](http://merchantos.com/makebeta/php/scraping-links-with-php). This, however has the downside of not being able to process JavaScript itself, making all dynamic fields in the remote form invisible to your PHP script.

With regards to cookies, cURL should process cookies automatically for you. Check out the [curl_setopt() manual](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for information about cURL settings.

Comment: Why can't i just inject the values of the form by ID? Example: site has option field. select qty. -- why can't I just pass <hidden field=qty value=100 and get the result of the form based on this information? btw not trying to hack anything or sniff. Just need to get pricing in real-time for a specific product.

Comment: you certainly can do that - provided that the field qty is on the page at the time you request it... if it's loaded via AJAX, cURL won't be able to run AJAX (being a JavaScript, which is interpreted on the client's browser) and you won't see it on page... for injecting code onto a remote page, see the same domain policy link in my answer

Comment: It is on the page at the time of load. AJAX is controlled by a Hidden field  set to value="RELOAD" i am also passing that field to get the result but no dice.

Comment: if you disable JavaScript entirely, does that field still appear at the load time on that page? there can also be checks on the original page preventing any outside scripts scraping the page (like referrer checks or even AJAX/hidden fields/special session variable checks)

Comment: Yep disabling JS does not affect the page. It still loads all the fields the same.

Comment: you can try to recreate the form on a testing HTML page locally and submit it - and see what it returns... if nothing, you're most probably out of luck on that website

Comment: I did recreate it. Just not sure how to pass the POST to their site and then intercept the result.

Comment: if you see the form on their page, simply copy-paste it... it must have an URL (action parameter) where it will be posted after you click submit

Comment: Yes it posts to itself. But If I just copy and paste the form and hit submit I am redirected to their website.

Comment: that would mean you're out of luck on the website, since they have obviously incorporated means that do not allow external forms manipulation on their website

Comment: I'll report back if I ever get through. Thanks anyway